# Unable to execute GRASS 7.8 in RStudio

Tags: r, grass-gis, osgeo4w

Using the initGRASS command in RStudio on Windows, I get the following error after I installed a new GRASS version on a new path:

```
Error : XML content does not seem to be XML: 'proj_get_authorities_from_database: Cannot find proj.db'
In addition: Warning message:
In system(cmd0, intern = TRUE) :
  running command 'g.proj.exe --interface-description' had status 5
Error in parseGRASS(cmd, legacyExec = legacyExec) : g.proj not parsed
```

Code snippet:

```
initGRASS("C:/GRASS GIS 7.8",
          home = tempdir(),
          mapset = "PERMANENT",
          override = TRUE)
```

For some reason RStudio computes something when I execute a GRASS function, but doesn't readRAST any result but showing the error message above.

The environmental variables, which I checked in the Grass shell, seem to be okay to me (considering: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/blob/master/mswindows/env.bat).

Can anybody help solving the problem or at least explain the error message?

I just tried to use the **Grass version 7.6** and it **works**. In the ongoing progress I will see, if using this version will last for my work.

Comment: not a solution but it looks like you're using windows. open up the start menu and type "environmental variables". The window that opens will include a PATH variable. I wouldbn't have expected R Studio to rely on  that though so I wouldn't expect that editing it would solve your problem.

Comment: Thx @Hugh_Kelley, if I understood you correctly, than you ment some Windows-Shell. But what I ment was the OSGeo4w Shell as you can see in the link above. Couldnt the problem rely to that? The problem came up with installing a new GRASS version on a new path.

Comment: %PATH% is a global environemntal variable on windows so any shell will have access to it. It's a list of places for the computer to look for programs to run. In that script, a place is being appended to the list. You can see your current using the directions in my previous comment.

Comment: Okay. So I'm still stucked. But does anybody in the world understand what the error message means? There must be someone out there who knows what "status 5" means for example, no?

Comment: To me as a noob it seems like there is some comunication problem between RStudio and the GRASS- project database. Seems like the problem is caused by some kind of false installation. Did I forget something? I tried several GRASS versions which I had on my PC at once, but only one of them worked. Maybe I have to link RStudio with the Grass version besides using the initGRASS function or I have to choose another installation path?

Comment: do you have a specific reason for using grass via r? The installation that comes with qgis works right out of the box. Managing environments and getting some of these gis packages set up correctly on Windows is a pretty much always a huge hassle.

Comment: I already wrote a relatively long code that worked in most parts until now. It's also part of my master thesis and also gives the known adventages of code based working. Another part of my work is QGIS based, but I really want to generate the basic data in R.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a slight elaboration on the answer given by @markusN that you linked to, as the issue does seem to be the same and related to the GRASS GIS environmental variables. (Here is the link given by @markusN again, which should help you set the necessary environmental variables correctly: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/blob/master/mswindows/env.bat)

First start GRASS GIS and go to the shell. Since you appear to be on Windows you can then type 'set' and hit enter to see all of the environmental variables. If, instead, you want to see where specifically GRASS_PYTHON is pointing for example, you can type 'set GRASS_PYTHON'. If this is not set then you will get the message "Environmental variable GRASS_PYTHON not defined". You can use this to check that the variables listed in the link are set correctly.

As for the words with percentage signs around them in the link, they are placeholders. So before the commands given in the link can be run, you need to make sure GISBASE points to your local installation of GRASS GIS. When you give a command with %GISBASE% in it, this will then be replaced by the full path to the installation. Try typing "set GISBASE". If this is not defined then type "set GISBASE=[path to installation]" replacing the bracketed text with the path to your local installation. After that you should be able to use the commands listed in the link to set the necessary environmental variables if they are not set correctly.

Comment: Thanks @humperderp. All environmental variables seem to be set correctly. There are no specific settings to be set in RStudio?

Comment: Have you tried running the code outside RStudio, just using the basic R command line interface? Just to try and identify if the issue is limited to RStudio

Comment: Thank you so far. Running the code using the basic R command line doesn't work either. Shall I post the Grass Gis environmental variables? Could it has something to do with OSGeo (which, how I understood, is responsible for communication between the programms) or the windows- and/or grass tmp-folder-path?

Comment: As you can see in my newest edit above, the Grass version 7.6 works for now.