# NA values as result from Grass functions (r.slope.aspect, r.sim.water) in R

Tags: r, grass-gis, hydrology, terrain

As the result from r.slope.aspect I get a raster with only NA values. r.param.scale works, but doesnt generate dx and dy maps, which I both need for r.sim.water function.

Code snippet 1 (initialize GRASS):

```
initGRASS("C:/GRASS GIS 7.8",
          home = tempdir(),
          mapset = "PERMANENT",
          override = TRUE)

execGRASS(cmd = "g.proj",
          flags = c("c", "quiet"))

use_sp()

writeRAST(x = as(dem_interpoliert,"SpatialGridDataFrame"),
          vname = "interpoliert",
          flags = c("overwrite", "quiet"))


execGRASS("g.region",
          parameters = list(raster = "interpoliert"),
          flags = c("quiet","p"))
```

Code snippet 2: Generate dx/dy (after using the r.param.scale elev-parameter on "dem_interpoliert", it became "interpoliert_elev"):

```
execGRASS(cmd = "r.slope.aspect",
          flags = c("overwrite","a","e"),
          parameters = list(elevation ="interpoliert_elev",
                            dx = "E-W_slope",
                            dy = "N-S_slope"))
```

Large Raster Layer "dem_interpoliert" (for g.region):

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2945, 3889, 11453105  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.9, 0.9  (x, y)
extent     : 325999.9, 329500, 5608849, 5611500  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : var1.pred 
values     : 355.4881, 569.02  (min, max)
```

"interpoliert_elev" (for r.slope.aspect after smoothing "dem_interpoliert" with r.param.scale):

```
Object of class SpatialGridDataFrame
Object of class SpatialGrid
Grid topology:
  cellcentre.offset cellsize cells.dim
1          326000.3      0.9      3889
2         5608849.9      0.9      2945
SpatialPoints:
                  s1      s2
       [1,] 326000.3 5611500
       [2,] 326001.2 5611500
     ...
     [499,] 326448.5 5611500
     [500,] 326449.4 5611500
 [ erreichte getOption("max.print") --  11452605 Zeilen ausgelassen ]
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80
+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 

Data summary:
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  355.5   423.4   462.7   465.8   506.3   569.0   81864
```

Seems like there are a lot of NAs in "interpoliert_elev" but result looks fine after plotting:

[image: interpoliert_elev]

I also tried to use "dem_interpoliert" with r.slope.aspect, also with NA-result.

---

Now I generated the dx and dy map in QGIS with r.slope.aspect, so that I was able now to use r.sim.water function. So, input data seems to be okay, because using it works in QGIS. r.sim.water executed, but also resulted in Na values (images below).

Code snippet:

```
execGRASS(cmd = "r.sim.water",
          flags = c("overwrite"),
          parameters = list(elevation = "interpoliert_elev",
                            dx = "dx",
                            dy = "dy",
                            rain_value = 50,
                            man_value = 0.368,
                            depth = "depth",
                            discharge = "discharge",
                            error = "error",
                            nwalkers = 9000000,
                            walkers_output = "walkers",
                            niterations = 180,
                            output_step = 5))
```

[image]
Example of r.sim.water raster input (dy map)

[image]
Depth map by r.sim.water. Notice the hole inside.

---

After assigning a crs to the GRASS- project, r.slope.aspect works now.

`execGRASS(cmd = "g.proj", parameters = list(proj4 = "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"), flags = c("c", "quiet"))`

r.sim.water still doesn't work and gives a SpatialGridDataFrame with only NA (but no hole anymore).

Comment: I don't seem to have any issues with r.slope.aspect when I apply your code to my own raster data. Could the issue be with the raster you are creating?

Comment: I've changed the subject to R instead of RStudio.

Comment: Thx @humperderp for trying. Please note my edits above.

Comment: I don't quite follow this part: '"interpoliert_elev" (for r.slope.aspect after smoothing with r.param.scale)' which I can't see in your code. Are you saying you are passing the output from r.param.scale to r.slope.aspect? Presumably using the option output=elev with r.param.scale? Have you tried just passing "dem_interpoliert" directly to r.slope.aspect?

Comment: @humperderp, thats correct. I used r.param.scale with output = elev before, to smooth kriging artifacts. I also had the idea, that NAs got removed by using this function. Unfortunately it is not possible to pass "dem_interpoliert" directly, because of the following error I want di discuss in another thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377481/how-to-set-grass-related-environmental-variables

Comment: @humperderp, passing "dem_interpoliert" directly to r.param.scale leads to the same wrong result.